# Excel "Array Constants" not readable as VBA Arrays (without parsing)

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Excel allegedly [allows the storage of arrays of constants](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/more-arrays-introducing-array-constants-in-excel-HA001087291.aspx) in individual cells (e.g. A1`={1,2,3,4,5}`). This is referred to as an "Array Constant." This should make for a very powerful feature allowing users to get more than 2 dimensions out of a spreadsheet. However, I can't seem to figure out how to extract the actual data without having to parse it as a string first. The latter method defeats the whole purpose of the array constant.

If one gets `Range('A1').Value` from the example above, it returns `1`.

Also, `IsArray(Range("A1"))` returns `False` while `IsArray(Range("A1:A2"))` returns `True`.

Am I missing something, or are these "Array Constants", not actually "Arrays" but just Strings or Doubles?

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to use an array stored in one cell, even the worksheet functions can't do that. You have to store the array in as many cells as there are elements.

Comment: You can get the array by using `Range("A1").FormulaArray`. Good thing is that if the Range doesn't contain Array then it will return `Null`

Answer (score 0):

> Am I missing something...

I'm afraid you may be... ;-(

Here's the relevant text from the article

> To create a horizontal constant
>
> 1. Use the workbook from the previous column, or start a new workbook.
> 2. **Select cells A1 through E1.**
> 3. In the formula bar, enter the following formula and press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER:

So the article doesn't show an array being stored in a single cell, but a range of cells. Entering the formula as described in a single cell will return the first element in the array only. Checking the `Value` property for the range using VBA confirms this.

Comment: Yes, but it also says "You create array constants by entering a list of items and then manually (yes, manually) surrounding the list with braces ({ })"

Comment: @Tim_Y Yes, but those can only be used inline as a part of a formula, not stored on their own to be referenced later.

Comment: That's what I think as well now. I think what page is somewhat misleading.